# How to save a html5 canvas image to mssql varbinary(max) field?

Tags: javascript, sql, asp.net, vb.net, html

**JAVASCRIPT - SAVE CANVAS IMAGE TO DATAURL**

This code binds the base64 string to a hiddenfield on click.

```
save.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  var dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL();
  $('txtbx').val(dataUrl);
});
```

**VB.NET - SUBMIT BASE64 STRING TO SQL**

This code submits the base64 string to the database on click. **(As `VarChar`)**

```
Protected Sub btn_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btn.Click
  Dim base64 As String = hidUrl.Value
  Dim base64Decode As String = base64.Replace("data:image/png;base64,", "")

  Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("sp", con)
  cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

  Dim image As New SqlParameter("@image", SqlDbType.VarChar, -1)
  image .Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
  cmd.Parameters.Add(image).Value = base64Decode

  con.Open()
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
  con.Close()
End Sub
```

---

### QUESTION

How to either:

- **Save canvas image as varbinary string?**
- **convert base64 string to varbinary?**

Any alternative solutions to get the image string to a varbinary field is welcome.

I have read a lot of documentation on this but have been unable to implement a working example. I now need some expert guidance on the matter.

---

**SIMPLE SOLUTIONS**

The answer was simple wrap the string as follows:

```
Convert.FromBase64String(base64Decode)
```

Comment: Could you post the code for the stored procedure? You could simply update the stored procedure and cast the base64 string to varbinary there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convert the base64 string to a binary data type, use [Convert.FromBase64String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.frombase64string(v=vs.110).aspx), then with the byte array you can store it as binary in your database.

I did this quick test in a form and it worked fine:

```
        //got this datauri from http://corehtml5canvas.com/code-live/ch01/example-1.1/example.html
        var datauri = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAlgAAAEsCAYAAAAfPc2WAAAaqklEQVR4Xu3dS6LrNBYFUN4UqqZIj/HQY4owBapCKpWfbOvI2365V4sWcJ1jafkk2rET58cv/iFAgAABAgQIEIgK/IhWU4wAAQIECBAgQOAXAUsTECBAgAABAgTCAgJWGFQ5AgQIECBAgICApQcIECBAgAABAmEBASsMqhwBAgQIECBAQMDSAwQIECBAgACBsICAFQZVjgABAgQIECAgYOkBAgQIECBAgEBYQMAKgypHgAABAgQIEBCw9AABAgQIECBAICwgYIVBlSNAgAABAgQICFh6gAABAgQIECAQFhCwwqDKESBAgAABAgQELD1AgAABAgQIEAgLCFhhUOUIECBAgAABAgKWHiBAgAABAgQIhAUErDCocgQIECBAgAABAUsPECBAgAABAgTCAgJWGFQ5AgQIECBAgICApQcIECBAgAABAmEBASsMqhwBAgQIECBAQMDSAwQIECBAgACBsICAFQZVjgABAgQIECAgYOkBAgQIECBAgEBYQMAKgypHgAABAgQIEBCw9AABAgQIECBAICwgYIVBlSNAgAABAgQICFh6gAABAgQIECAQFhCwwqDKESBAgAABAgQELD1AgAABAgQIEAgLCFhhUOUIECBAgAABAgKWHiBAgAABAgQIhAUErDCocgQIECBAgAABAUsPECBAgAABAgTCAgJWGFQ5AgQIECBAgICApQcIECBAgAABAmEBASsMqhwBAgQIECBAQMDSAwQIECBAgACBsICAFQZVjgABAgQIECAgYOkBAgQIECBAgEBYQMAKgypHgAABAgQIEBCw9AABAgQIECBAICwgYIVBlSNAgAABAgQICFh6gAABAgQIECAQFhCwwqDKESBAgAABAgQELD1AgAABAgQIEAgLCFhhUOUIECBAgAABAgKWHiBAgAABAgQIhAUErDCocgQIECBAgAABAUsPECBAgAABAgTCAgJWGFQ5AgQIECBAgICApQcIECBAgAABAmEBASsMqhwBAgQIECBAQMDSAwQIECBAgACBsICAFQZVjgABAgQIECAgYOkBAgQIECBAgEBYQMAKgypHgAABAgQIEBCw9AABAgQIECBAICwgYIVBlSNAgAABAgQICFh6gAABAgQIECAQFhCwwqDKESBAgAABAgQELD1AgAABAgQIEAgLCFhhUOUIECBAgAABAgKWHiBAgAABAgQIhAUErDCocgQIECBAgAABAUsPECBAgAABAgTCAgJWGFQ5AgQIECBAgICApQcIECBAgAABAmEBASsMqhwBAgQIECBAQMDSAwQIECBAgACBsICAFQZVjgABAgQIECAgYOkBAgQIECBAgEBYQMAKgypHgAABAgQIEBCw9AABAgQIECBAICwgYIVBlSNAgAABAgQICFh6gAABAgQIECAQFhCwwqDKESBAgAABAgQELD1AgAABAgQIEAgLCFhhUOUIECBAgAABAgKWHiBAgAABAgQIhAUErDCocgQIECBAgAABAUsPECBAgAABAgTCAgJWGFQ5AgQIECBAgICApQcIECBAgAABAmEBASsMqhwBAgQIECBAQMDSAwQIECBAgACBsICAFQZVjgABAgQIECAgYOkBAgQIECBAgEBYQMAKgypHgAABAgQIEBCw9AABAgQIECBAICwgYIVBlSNAgAABAgQICFh6gAABAgQIECAQFhCwwqDKESBAgAABAgQELD1AgAABAgQIEAgLCFhhUOUIECBAgAABAgKWHiBAgAABAgQIhAUErDCocgQIECBAgAABAUsPECBAgAABAgTCAgJWGFQ5AgQIECBAgICApQcIECBAgAABAmEBASsMqhwBAgQIECBAQMDSAwQIECBAgACBsICAFQZVjgABAgQIECAgYOkBAgQIECBAgEBYQMAKgypHgAABAgQIEBCw9AABAgQIECBAICwgYIVBlSNAgAABAgQICFh6gAABAgQIECAQFhCwwqDKESBAgAABAgQELD1AgAABAgQIEAgLCFhhUOUIECBAgAABAgKWHiBAgAABAgQIhAUErDCocgQIECBAgAABAUsPECBAgAABAgTCAgJWGFQ5AgQIECBAgICApQcIECBAgAABAmEBASsMqhwBAgQIECBAQMDSAwQIECBAgACBsICAFQZVjgABAgQIECAgYOkBAgQIECBAgEBYQMAKgypHgAABAgQIEBCw9AABAgQIECBAICwgYIVBlSNAgAABAgQICFh6gAABAgQIECAQFhCwwqDKESBAgAABAgQELD1AgAABAgQIEAgLCFhhUOUIEMgI/Pr7n3+vVfrjt397/cpQq0KAwAECXqAOQFWyJfB3Y7H8Eeq/Vu3LGFL19x7R6viOtNo7l2MffwlVf/z2r9JOfv39r1+ErRKZjQkQOEEgtMCdMFK7+OICf/99WQhv/1wX0VQAeq592Ue2/l766viOtNo7lyMffw+Wj72yfhbrHsYErSOPjdoECFQFBKyqmO0HBY4MDdUAMziF4YdVx3ek1fAkDnzgNVj1hqqlgdzPfKWC+4FTVpoAgW8vIGB9+0P8KRM8MjRUA8zZJtXxHWl19ty39vdu8/iIpUt/S5/PErK2vP2dAIGzBASss6Sn38+RoaEaYM4+GNXxHWl19tzX9rccrq7Baumza7eaP360gpaQ9UnH2FgIzCsgYM177E+e+ZGhoRpgTp76f4PC6+Wv9c+IHWl19tyX9tcOV88fcN+61Ld8afGzPoP3KebGQYDAmQIC1pnaU+/ryNBQDTBnH4jq+I60Onvurf1thautYPVac61etdYn+BgDAQLfQUDA+g5H8UvM4cjQUA0wZ4NVx3ek1dlzfw9Dl/9TO6PXM2Yhq0fJNgQInCcgYJ1nPfmejgwN1QBz9qGoju9Iq7Pnvn22KXc5r+r8sy3snwCB7ywgYH3no/tRczsyNGQX1vwdxKvjy1jl57G3oZYcLnUTl/Kqzsvz2bK7PPKom5suf0Py6925/kzHrX0ddbz2Pis8/vsKCFjf99h+2MwyoaE9qczC2nsX8dvlrf4X7Or49lndFpqeO6Kfe3POqsNIC1/3cT82t28i9gW43h64jazWC+t36O/Z9/b+qr8asGU8Wm/rG6DP+92e19o4+/a1bx9bTv5O4F1AwNIVJwnsCw3rg0ws3P03u7wFl/4X7Or49ljV7oZ+7i0Nqg4jrfm62PYFq8dbQlRuePrYC9uBe+249vVf3/7e9zMepKu1av13O8J983rthz6z1j6OPAM50rUe8z0FBKzveVw/cFZ7QsPWdPYs3LUX6ceR9C8K1fHVrR7PflQCwuvik7lU1zpeF+fn+1Zd/MYX/q2eqPx9vAce/bbnsnRc2x/QX5vBul2135b2VK1Tn8fY8+nyqPF93eyErMpzxLYjAgLWiJrHDAjUQ0P/TqoLwa3y2n2UXm90eT0T8vo5j74zQNXxjVgtLzivlwqXAljfXPqPyvOWVYPR/VQft+bWutlp++am18V66/c1W8f1+RuVrbNg63etb52hS1lXzl7199/1COUcWyHt/v+Wn7fbgbjaS7Yn8CwgYOmIkwRGQkPv0EYXlKXH3fb7uHgtX/rYPhNTHV/Vqr24Ld+082fcoLNq0Hvs92zXdli/2WmuD97PpKx/lqh9a4trWHlXqISjluG7zXKfb/Vfe3xLQWvs7FzrOXv5f/fP4LXeHAlZe54/HrslIGBtCfl7SKD97j1UfOC+Smvhau1zO8uL8vKLdTVcVALWWkjY+vzRnsdWj1zVoFp/ZPs9YxqxWwoitzNlY33XE7AuOttn2B4NKzaVbV+PU/vS8S189QTH5W2f5/O5l6hHetdjvoKAgPUVjtK3GOP4ZyZGpl/5KZr74nP5t61QchtNZVGpbHt91/14tmJsLuPzqC/GPUeoatBTc+82FefWvqpzWjvT03O89u1vT8CqnL2q7ee939f7b8+Zub3He2+/efxsAgLWbEf8p833KwSsnkXuHrBa74gzZxN6F4L2ZZz+kDgSFkcbqBoORvfT+7jrmZPL1s+3taj1QO2O9AmD3t5YCuo9byLa42yfoT3bcV/AandH5Zj39pftCPz3FQYCgXMEPjdg1d9xt4NJ7l1+7yKaWLCvC/E1aPz1/1YYN1nqpj0L4xEdOnp/p9ex9B6r6pmafsflQD3aH605LQWz9Xt79R25yjjbfXTZT89tMupvPvpmYCsCLQEBS1+cJLD0op3Zff+ZhMqL+dbYemv1brcc3DJnxtbmUx3jls16ELkuiFvfuqvu47ztH8969QfThHEl0L2Huj7z88Lw7fYiledv+8zx9rcxz+sOeyJwFRCwdMJJAtWFoTKsysK1fPmjssdbQOhbGCrjqyyKSdPqGKtaR9evjqd/++Vbc1xrfKWAtR1sK5cH+w2vTn/+c6b09s/jtzX7nkfX58bSLR6W6m2f2arNw9YEegUErF4p2+0USIaB16FUFu+lbcem17cwVMYnYI0dicyjHkPA6/3DbntYu5HrsV9IqPTGbbTVy7+Zs1dHO67dR+seIu890f+rC5k+UoXARUDA0gcnCXxuwEoCtBfYIwJWdeHcmmV1jFv19oTgau3927d+B3D8jvhLH5pOGI88jyqhqbLtu/tZjtc9L9+s9HVkr2e3nNXa/5xRYVtAwNo2skVEYGRh6N1xZeF637Z3Lz3bnRmw+s6e9Yz6sk3FsLfm43ZH1x8Z0/Wy1eNPHlWqtB73eWewKsd2/PLgXsexXl6+iejacXw8boJWpeNtWxUQsKpith8U+OyAlXuhvX9t/Q5VDRc9VtWaW4ctXe91f2f+FuHjN9uWv4K/9AHrltS1P9rfPPzsz2DdZlPvqe1fKLjXvvxbzxm/JcexgPW8/+t/9Z3VErK2Xg/8PSEgYCUU1egQ6HmB7yjT3KQSDrKfwWqP+HVRr4zv/YzD8lmRpGl1jCPHqjXe66I4Uq39mKV9tPbTPpu5Fqbex1o5Bgnjyv4ehbYu/VV+Guc9PLfC1bLj3ufHWre8h+v133JM91+uk1X6+gLBF7avj2EGRwqMLgw9Y6osXJVte/bds011n71WvdsdMcaemtsLcd9tAyr76rVeCleXW0dUFt3KMegd23qA6D9jthywLn95tm8H0+3f6ks4JlxaZs9hqxW0+s/SVXrQtgT+9yoCgsA5ApWFqDqiygt0e9vthaQ6psrith5EKmewRuZRvxfRqMUZlwl7e6F3u/6w8x5ajgiYe55Ha4/dOsO15PAzHEf6r/15LQFrxNJjegWcweqVst1OgT0Lw9auKy/yyUW+9y7WlfFd5tprVa3bdmwFrPu3rrKX7y4j2Pd5m0TgSX0Ds+pf3b59VmbsDFa7r66B/F/NY7Id1hPzeR/XelB9fs5tj/GIkLv1euTvBK4CApZOOEmgNzSMDKf6Qt++HFL/LFDvfnu3u82916pa98izEL3HbWnM/7wc7Xg9eg9Nywv1z3JL7Le3N9rh7DXgLn0Tsu++UYn5VALW6Fm2R4vUmHv73XYzC+x4QZuZzdzrAnsWhq29VV80E5cJK/usbNs+09D7e3PVM0/nXR7sWeRGQ9ZauGrVrB6PvrCyHOjawXl7+/Z+x89gLfXW+93o+84MZRzbH5Bv/YxS/nlbfb5svRL5O4FHAQFLP5wk8FkB6/Wd/G2x611Ylh6f+c3AitX4GaH1cDUadnra6X3M97BR3W87XK2Hl30L9drtHT7zPljL4fY23tc7r/c+D1qXe/seew17refR8rFbvrx/fczlVhpr/6QuDff0uG0IuESoB04TqISG6qBG3km3f9Ps8fMo7Rfs6tmS97MG64v/+/bb37RbDlmtxW7ph4rvi1TrXl7VY7K1fTtk9Qet5cV523f5mKyFg56baX5+wGrP/Xa0tvv/Oay1AtLWB8f3OdZ6/T7ayiXkrd71dwJ9As5g9TnZarfApwWs5YVm6TfobgT9lzRuj6gGwKpVT1h5P4D1eexugpcCy+N+Dlp9Y38MCduf59o6i3a/bPbaD6+X6Pov2VX7oOVd7Y3tGo9bbIWj92rrjvfPct1uf3GtsHTma/sYbr3BWe7R475ckX5eqPddBASs73IkP34eiYVhaZKjC9fYT228jmL8DFPfb9Zt17+GxdbC1dsW95tC7vmgee/eHrdbD1nVin1Wy8H3eYFvh4HXbfoX7tE+XfaqzXd93mN3N+85k7js+BheK0G1947tS/3js1fVZ5btRwQErBE1jxkQ+MSAdV9wRsJJ/4t0dWEdtRoLWf3zGDjsXQ8ZG/dj6bE5jO33eV+VY1vZtu/NxFjAugbytbNI259neg59+58/VZuxY3cZ51ivdDWyjQg8CQhYGuIkgdHQ0DO86otzq+b9/jpbv6lWf4Gujm+vVd/i83zp6+wzV/uOwfNCefmvPeOveq3/1EvvjWHvc6iMfW9v3N9U7PuA+uvx63v+LPdc9TlyDYn3Uaz/BuHn9XrP65ptvrqAgPXVj+CXGX/vTTlHJtSqvWfRXap3G1tlQXxdCB7nt3yJ8F2hus+1/Y7OY+TYjD5m6xgcMYetfVaOV6v/En2afB691hrpsfWgXOvjPT5bx27P68FoD3vc7AIC1uwdYP4ECBAgQIBAXEDAipMqSIAAAQIECMwuIGDN3gHmT4AAAQIECMQFBKw4qYIECBAgQIDA7AIC1uwdYP4ECBAgQIBAXEDAipMqSIAAAQIECMwuIGDN3gHmT4AAAQIECMQFBKw4qYIECBAgQIDA7AIC1uwdYP4ECBAgQIBAXEDAipMqSIAAAQIECMwuIGDN3gHmT4AAAQIECMQFBKw4qYIECBAgQIDA7AIC1uwdYP4ECBAgQIBAXEDAipMqSIAAAQIECMwuIGDN3gHmT4AAAQIECMQFBKw4qYIECBAgQIDA7AIC1uwdYP4ECBAgQIBAXEDAipMqSIAAAQIECMwuIGDN3gHmT4AAAQIECMQFBKw4qYIECBAgQIDA7AIC1uwdYP4ECBAgQIBAXEDAipMqSIAAAQIECMwuIGDN3gHmT4AAAQIECMQFBKw4qYIECBAgQIDA7AIC1uwdYP4ECBAgQIBAXEDAipMqSIAAAQIECMwuIGDN3gHmT4AAAQIECMQFBKw4qYIECBAgQIDA7AIC1uwdYP4ECBAgQIBAXEDAipMqSIAAAQIECMwuIGDN3gHmT4AAAQIECMQFBKw4qYIECBAgQIDA7AIC1uwdYP4ECBAgQIBAXEDAipMqSIAAAQIECMwuIGDN3gHmT4AAAQIECMQFBKw4qYIECBAgQIDA7AIC1uwdYP4ECBAgQIBAXEDAipMqSIAAAQIECMwuIGDN3gHmT4AAAQIECMQFBKw4qYIECBAgQIDA7AIC1uwdYP4ECBAgQIBAXEDAipMqSIAAAQIECMwuIGDN3gHmT4AAAQIECMQFBKw4qYIECBAgQIDA7AIC1uwdYP4ECBAgQIBAXEDAipMqSIAAAQIECMwuIGDN3gHmT4AAAQIECMQFBKw4qYIECBAgQIDA7AIC1uwdYP4ECBAgQIBAXEDAipMqSIAAAQIECMwuIGDN3gHmT4AAAQIECMQFBKw4qYIECBAgQIDA7AIC1uwdYP4ECBAgQIBAXEDAipMqSIAAAQIECMwuIGDN3gHmT4AAAQIECMQFBKw4qYIECBAgQIDA7AIC1uwdYP4ECBAgQIBAXEDAipMqSIAAAQIECMwuIGDN3gHmT4AAAQIECMQFBKw4qYIECBAgQIDA7AIC1uwdYP4ECBAgQIBAXEDAipMqSIAAAQIECMwuIGDN3gHmT4AAAQIECMQFBKw4qYIECBAgQIDA7AIC1uwdYP4ECBAgQIBAXEDAipMqSIAAAQIECMwuIGDN3gHmT4AAAQIECMQFBKw4qYIECBAgQIDA7AIC1uwdYP4ECBAgQIBAXEDAipMqSIAAAQIECMwuIGDN3gHmT4AAAQIECMQFBKw4qYIECBAgQIDA7AIC1uwdYP4ECBAgQIBAXEDAipMqSIAAAQIECMwuIGDN3gHmT4AAAQIECMQFBKw4qYIECBAgQIDA7AIC1uwdYP4ECBAgQIBAXEDAipMqSIAAAQIECMwuIGDN3gHmT4AAAQIECMQFBKw4qYIECBAgQIDA7AIC1uwdYP4ECBAgQIBAXEDAipMqSIAAAQIECMwuIGDN3gHmT4AAAQIECMQFBKw4qYIECBAgQIDA7AIC1uwdYP4ECBAgQIBAXEDAipMqSIAAAQIECMwuIGDN3gHmT4AAAQIECMQFBKw4qYIECBAgQIDA7AIC1uwdYP4ECBAgQIBAXEDAipMqSIAAAQIECMwuIGDN3gHmT4AAAQIECMQFBKw4qYIECBAgQIDA7AIC1uwdYP4ECBAgQIBAXEDAipMqSIAAAQIECMwuIGDN3gHmT4AAAQIECMQFBKw4qYIECBAgQIDA7AIC1uwdYP4ECBAgQIBAXEDAipMqSIAAAQIECMwuIGDN3gHmT4AAAQIECMQFBKw4qYIECBAgQIDA7AIC1uwdYP4ECBAgQIBAXEDAipMqSIAAAQIECMwuIGDN3gHmT4AAAQIECMQFBKw4qYIECBAgQIDA7AIC1uwdYP4ECBAgQIBAXEDAipMqSIAAAQIECMwuIGDN3gHmT4AAAQIECMQFBKw4qYIECBAgQIDA7AIC1uwdYP4ECBAgQIBAXEDAipMqSIAAAQIECMwuIGDN3gHmT4AAAQIECMQFBKw4qYIECBAgQIDA7AIC1uwdYP4ECBAgQIBAXEDAipMqSIAAAQIECMwuIGDN3gHmT4AAAQIECMQFBKw4qYIECBAgQIDA7AIC1uwdYP4ECBAgQIBAXEDAipMqSIAAAQIECMwuIGDN3gHmT4AAAQIECMQFBKw4qYIECBAgQIDA7AIC1uwdYP4ECBAgQIBAXEDAipMqSIAAAQIECMwuIGDN3gHmT4AAAQIECMQFBKw4qYIECBAgQIDA7AIC1uwdYP4ECBAgQIBAXEDAipMqSIAAAQIECMwuIGDN3gHmT4AAAQIECMQFBKw4qYIECBAgQIDA7AIC1uwdYP4ECBAgQIBAXEDAipMqSIAAAQIECMwuIGDN3gHmT4AAAQIECMQFBKw4qYIECBAgQIDA7AIC1uwdYP4ECBAgQIBAXEDAipMqSIAAAQIECMwu8B+03ZHSzNSl5QAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==";
        var base64 = datauri.Substring(datauri.IndexOf(',') + 1);

        var binary = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);

        pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(binary));
```

Remember to change SP parameter to work with varbinary.

Your decode function is overcomplicated you don't need that, just change your parameter creation:

```
Dim image As New SqlParameter("@image", SqlDbType.VarBinary, -1)
  image .Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
  cmd.Parameters.Add(image ).Value = Convert.FromBase64String(base64.Substring(base64.IndexOf(',') + 1););
```

You don't need any char arrays or stream, just remove the useless parts of the URI (`substring` piece, and convert it to a byte array (`Convert...`).

ADO.NET will automaticaly convert the byte array to the varbinary expected by MSSQL.

Comment: Tried this as per Microsoft documentation but received error that the string was too long to convert. Any ideas?

Comment: did you remove all the "not usefull" pieces before trying to convert it? The Data URI format is `data:[<MIME-type>][;charset=<encoding>][;base64],<data>` (from Wikipedia), the only piece which you should send to the function is the `<data>`

Comment: Received Error: "The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters."

Comment: There is something wrong with your code, the base64 string is being interpreted as a path??

Comment: your help is really appreciated here. I know I am so close. I have added the function I am using to convert. The string seems correct but the above error happens.

Comment: edited the answer, forget your Decode function, it has a lot of useless code (sorry), you have to just remove useless DATA URI pieces, get the byte array and send it to ADO.NET

Comment: I can't believe what ive been doing. The answer was simply Convert.FromBase64String(image). Many thanks for your assistance on this.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you need to update your table column [Image] to varbinary(max) first.

Then, update the procedure as below:

```
@image VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE  [tbl]
    SET     [Image] = cast('' as xml).value('xs:base64Binary(sql:variable("@image"))', 'varbinary(max)')

END
```

Try that and let us know if it works.

EDIT:

Looks like you do need to decode the data. I've updated the proc. Have a look at http://blog.falafel.com/t-sql-easy-base64-encoding-and-decoding/ for further info on encoding/decoding.

Comment: Will this convert the base64 string into a binary string?